# XCode 6 valid signing identities are not shown

Tags: xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile, sign

My problem is that XCode 6 doesn't show list of all possible identities and profiles that goes with selected identity on my working computer. If I put correct identity and provision profile by hand application can be build, deployed and runs without problem on device. For more complex work with signing identities and provision profiles I have to switch to other computer and reopen project on working computer.

Because I don't have enough reputation I cannot post image. In XCode beside signing identity in Build Setting arrows and provision profile are missing. Beside that the name for provision profile is missing too, instead of name, id of provisioning profile is shown.

I already tried to refresh developer accounts in preferences several times, multiple restart of computer and even reinstalled XCode6. I have tried many solutions from google without succes.

I'm assuming that problem is with XCode6 or connection between XCode6 and key chain access. Unfortunately there is no error message or something that could tell me what is not ok.

Last resort I think of is reinstalling MacOS and XCode, but this is something I would like to avoid.

Is there some kind of log file in XCode that could be inspecting for errors?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Xcode-->Preferences-->Accounts** and make sure to add your iTunes Developer account there (click on the + on the bottom left corner).

[image: Xcode Preferences]

**If it exists**, click on it and select View details, then Hit the refresh button on the bottom left corner to get your profiles from the portal

[image]

Comment: Like I mentioned in original question I already refreshed provisioning profiles in preferences several times and it didn't work. iTunes account and provisioning profiles should be valid, because I can build, deploy and run application on physical devices.

Comment: Can you explain what you do when you mention this: ` If I put correct identity and provision profile by hand application can be build, deployed and runs without problem on device` ?

Comment: For example in BuildSettings->Code Signing Identity->Debug text "iPhone Developer" is entered, under BuildSettings->Code Signing Identity->Release "iPhone Distribution" and in BuildSettings->Provisioning profile->Debug 2f222222-1111-3333-8454-98f8d3478abc (this is id of provisioning profile). I work on different applications for different customers and have more iTunes account and provisioning profiles and is pain to manage signing identities and provisioning profiles by entering text instead of selecting from list. Issue that I have that list doesn't appear in XCode.

Comment: Did you try manually importing the provisioning profiles directly from the developer portal ?